# How to close a cv2 window within a Flet program?

Tags: python, android, flutter, opencv, flet

The webcam window doesn't seem to close when any key is pressed including the "ESC" key?

Here is an excerpt from the Flet app:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def main(page : ft.Page):
    page.title = "fletCam"

    def update_images():
        while(cap.isOpened()):
            # Capture frame-by-frame
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                # encode the resulting frame
                jpg_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                b64_string = base64.b64encode(jpg_img[1]).decode('utf-8')
                image_box.src_base64 = b64_string
                page.update()
                k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
                if k == 27:  # close on ESC key
                   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            else:
                break
            time.sleep(1/115)
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm running this application on Windows 11

Comment: What window? The code you provided never calls any OpenCV HighGUI functions that would actually create on in the first place, so what do you want to close?

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your

```
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

Outside of your if + put your break condition in your while :

```
def update_images():
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            # encode the resulting frame
            jpg_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            b64_string = base64.b64encode(jpg_img[1]).decode('utf-8')
            image_box.src_base64 = b64_string
            page.update()
            
        if k == 27:  # close on ESC key
                break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to fix the issue in Flet!